# Parsing XML data from a string

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

What I want to do is grab the xml data from a string not a txt file. This works:

```
// xmlData.txt contains < m t='Hello' u='1337' />

XmlReader config = new XmlTextReader("../../xmldata.txt");
config.Read();
Console.WriteLine("Data: " + config.GetAttribute("t"));
```

But I want to parse it from a string not a document.

How do I parse XML data from a string?

Comment: Also, you could use System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse("string...")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `StringReader` and feed it to the `XmlTextReader`:

```
StringReader sr = new StringReader("<m t='Hello' u='1337'/>");
XmlReader config = new XmlTextReader(sr);
config.Read();
Console.WriteLine("Data: " + config.GetAttribute("t"));
```

Comment: Thanks. If anyone else is reading this you need to use System.IO :p

Comment: Correct, but @SwagBob, an XmlReader is still the wrong tool. It's cumbersome and used for very large files/streams. Make sure you know about `class XElement`.